# OLS, phenomenon { alpha = - mean(beta_2*x_orig)} : coincidence?

Tags: least-squares, polynomial

as suggested in the title, when with some data I perform this model:

```
y ~ alpha + beta_1 * x_1 + beta_2 * (x_1)^2 + error term
```

with OLS I SOMETIMES fall into the situation in which

```
alpha ~~ - mean(beta_2 * (x_1)^2)
```

this means that, on average, my model is equivalent to:

```
E(y) ~ E(beta_1 * x_1)
```

this, to me, is huge.(Edit based on asagen comment)

in order to better understand what I am implying at, please look at the attached graph[image]

now, statistically I can't think of anything of relevance but, the economic implication of such phenomenon in my study is game changing stuff. thus I am wondering whether I am doing something seriously wrong (any number of input is appreciated) and there is some property in the data for which this stuff happens.

from an economical point of view, I am very suspicious of such result thus I am seeking to add some statistical soundness in order to make order.

Comment: You're doing a fit by penalizing on the squared errors to a function you *chose*, but that does not mean the fit is a good one.  Plot the data and your fit before making conclusions.  Also just because your $\hat{y}$ on average is equal to the linear term, does not mean your fit is linear, in fact it's not.

Comment: you make a good point when you say the fit , punctually, is not linear BUT in my case - and the fault is with me for not pointing it out before - the aggregate result is of great significance as the regression results are important on a rolling basis. Thus what I am inferring has meaning (economically at least) for it could imply that a certain phenomenon on average(here represented by beta * x^2) cancels out another (represented by alpha)

Comment: Using OLS you're essentially getting the maximum likelihood given gaussian errors, so I would check that my errors are actually gaussian (like doing a run test or something).  Secondly, the expectation is not linear, the expectation is your determined model, i.e $\hat{y}=\beta_1x^2 + \beta_2x +\alpha$.  If you really want to average over all $x_1$ then you might as well average over the linear term as well, in which case you would get $E(y)=0$

Comment: you are right. p.s.: can you post it as an answer? so I can give you credit points.

Comment: I don't care too much about the points, feel free to submit an answer yourself